# How to make new anaconda env from yml file

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

[image]

I installed anaconda in C:\Program Files\Anaconda3. Every time to create a new env, I just do cmd and write:

```
conda create --name envname python=3.5
```

But how can i install a new env from the "environments.yml" file

[image]

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The above answers did not work for me with conda 4.7.12, but this (from the Anaconda documentation) did:

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

Comment: It's always best to first consider the documentation :) That really helps. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Worked for me on `conda 23.1.0`.

Answer (score 143):

`conda env create` allows an option `--file` for an environment file:

```
conda env create --name envname --file=environments.yml
```

Comment: Now it is `--file=environment.yml` and not -f, which fails.

Comment: a/o `conda v4.8.1` options `-f` and `--file` are both accepted for an environment definition file.

Comment: the `--name` arg is optional, bc it is already defined in environments.yml

Comment: You don't need the equal sign (`=`), replace the `--file==environments.yml` with `--file environments.yml` then you can have bash autocomplete

Answer (score 34):

To sum up (as of conda 4.8.4) `conda env create` and `conda create` are two fundamentally different commands.

## conda create

- this is the official (quasi-recommended) command to create envs, listed in the [general commands section of the docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands.html#)
- `conda create --file` expects a `requirements.txt`, **not** an `environment.yml`, each line in the given file is treated as a package-reference

## conda env create

- instead, this command is needed to create an environment from a given `environment.yml`
- environment.yml files have a specific syntax (e.g. for env name, source channels, packages)
- e.g. `conda env create --file environment.yml`
- some flags available with `conda create` are not available with `conda env create`, such as `--strict-channel-priority`, which may result in some confusion
- `conda env create` is only mentioned [deep into the docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html?highlight=environment.yml#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file) of conda (although I think it is the more common command to use)

Comment: I suppose `conda env create` could be made a little more prominent. I'm sure there was already a discussion over which was better to use, I wonder if any of it was publicly documented so we know why `conda create` won out? Probably because not everyone has an `environment.yml` handy...

Comment: I am personally a fan of 'conda env create'. However, I would really like to have all the flags from 'conda create'. Especially the --no-deps flag. With 'conda env create', to my knowledge, I am forced to use 'conda remove ...  --force ...' to get rid of the dependencies I don't care, which really annoying.

Comment: `conda env create --no-deps` makes not much sense: without dependencies, install the package (you want to install without dependencies) directly, e.g. in an empty conda environment.

Answer (score 27):

```
conda env create --file environment.yml
```

Answer (score 3):

Worked for me on `anaconda`, `mini conda` Replace the *`.yml file path`* to location of `environment.yml` file.

> conda env create --prefix ./env -f ../*`yml file path`*/environment.yml