# A weird requirements.txt format

Tags: python, jupyter, conda

I downloaded a `requirements.txt` file from a GitHub repository, but it appears to be little different than the normal format of `requirements.txt` file.

1. Can you tell me how the author generated this kind of `requirements.txt` file? Which tools did they use?
2. How can I use this particular file format to instantiate the Python environment? I have tried executing the commands `conda install --file requirements.txt` and `pip install -r  requirements.txt` on a Windows ‘ machine, but to no avail.

https://github.com/wvangansbeke/Unsupervised-Classification/blob/master/requirements.txt

```
""" This file contains a list of packages and their versions that were used to produce the results. """
  - _libgcc_mutex=0.1=main
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - bzip2=1.0.8=h7b6447c_0
  - ca-certificates=2020.1.1=0
  - cairo=1.14.12=h8948797_3
  - certifi=2020.4.5.1=py37_0
  - cffi=1.14.0=py37h2e261b9_0
  - cmake=3.14.0=h52cb24c_0
  - cudatoolkit=10.0.130=0
  - cycler=0.10.0=py37_0
  - dbus=1.13.12=h746ee38_0
  - easydict=1.9=py_0
  - expat=2.2.6=he6710b0_0
  - faiss-gpu=1.6.3=py37h1a5d453_0
  - ffmpeg=4.0=hcdf2ecd_0
  - fontconfig=2.13.0=h9420a91_0
  - freeglut=3.0.0=hf484d3e_5
  - freetype=2.9.1=h8a8886c_1
  - glib=2.63.1=h5a9c865_0
  - graphite2=1.3.13=h23475e2_0
  - gst-plugins-base=1.14.0=hbbd80ab_1
  - gstreamer=1.14.0=hb453b48_1
  - h5py=2.8.0=py37h989c5e5_3
  - harfbuzz=1.8.8=hffaf4a1_0
  - hdf5=1.10.2=hba1933b_1
  - icu=58.2=h9c2bf20_1
  - imageio=2.8.0=py_0
  - intel-openmp=2020.0=166
  - jasper=2.0.14=h07fcdf6_1
  - joblib=0.14.1=py_0
  - jpeg=9b=h024ee3a_2
  - kiwisolver=1.1.0=py37he6710b0_0
  - krb5=1.17.1=h173b8e3_0
  - ld_impl_linux-64=2.33.1=h53a641e_7
  - libcurl=7.69.1=h20c2e04_0
  - libedit=3.1.20181209=hc058e9b_0
  - libffi=3.2.1=hd88cf55_4
  - libgcc-ng=9.1.0=hdf63c60_0
  - libgfortran-ng=7.3.0=hdf63c60_0
  - libglu=9.0.0=hf484d3e_1
  - libopencv=3.4.2=hb342d67_1
  - libopus=1.3.1=h7b6447c_0
  - libpng=1.6.37=hbc83047_0
  - libprotobuf=3.11.4=hd408876_0
  - libssh2=1.9.0=h1ba5d50_1
  - libstdcxx-ng=9.1.0=hdf63c60_0
  - libtiff=4.1.0=h2733197_0
  - libuuid=1.0.3=h1bed415_2
  - libvpx=1.7.0=h439df22_0
  - libxcb=1.13=h1bed415_1
  - libxml2=2.9.9=hea5a465_1
  - matplotlib=3.1.3=py37_0
  - matplotlib-base=3.1.3=py37hef1b27d_0
  - mkl=2020.0=166
  - mkl-service=2.3.0=py37he904b0f_0
  - mkl_fft=1.0.15=py37ha843d7b_0
  - mkl_random=1.1.0=py37hd6b4f25_0
  - ncurses=6.2=he6710b0_0
  - ninja=1.9.0=py37hfd86e86_0
  - numpy=1.18.1=py37h4f9e942_0
  - numpy-base=1.18.1=py37hde5b4d6_1
  - olefile=0.46=py_0
  - opencv=3.4.2=py37h6fd60c2_1
  - openssl=1.1.1g=h7b6447c_0
  - pcre=8.43=he6710b0_0
  - pillow=7.0.0=py37hb39fc2d_0
  - pip=20.0.2=py37_1
  - pixman=0.38.0=h7b6447c_0
  - protobuf=3.11.4=py37he6710b0_0
  - py-opencv=3.4.2=py37hb342d67_1
  - pycparser=2.20=py_0
  - pyparsing=2.4.6=py_0
  - pyqt=5.9.2=py37h05f1152_2
  - python=3.7.7=hcf32534_0_cpython
  - python-dateutil=2.8.1=py_0
  - pytorch=1.4.0=py3.7_cuda10.0.130_cudnn7.6.3_0
  - pyyaml=5.3.1=py37h7b6447c_0
  - qt=5.9.7=h5867ecd_1
  - readline=8.0=h7b6447c_0
  - rhash=1.3.8=h1ba5d50_0
  - scikit-learn=0.22.1=py37hd81dba3_0
  - scipy=1.4.1=py37h0b6359f_0
  - setuptools=46.1.3=py37_0
  - sip=4.19.8=py37hf484d3e_0
  - six=1.14.0=py37_0
  - sqlite=3.31.1=h7b6447c_0
  - swig=3.0.12=h38cdd7d_3
  - tensorboardx=2.0=py_0
  - termcolor=1.1.0=py37_1
  - tk=8.6.8=hbc83047_0
  - torchvision=0.5.0=py37_cu100
  - tornado=6.0.4=py37h7b6447c_1
  - typing=3.6.4=py37_0
  - wheel=0.34.2=py37_0
  - xz=5.2.4=h14c3975_4
  - yaml=0.1.7=had09818_2
  - zlib=1.2.11=h7b6447c_3
  - zstd=1.3.7=h0b5b093_0
  - pip:
    - blis==0.4.1
    - catalogue==1.0.0
    - chardet==3.0.4
    - cymem==2.0.3
    - en-core-web-sm==2.2.5
    - idna==2.9
    - importlib-metadata==1.6.0
    - murmurhash==1.0.2
    - plac==1.1.3
    - preshed==3.0.2
    - requests==2.23.0
    - spacy==2.2.4
    - srsly==1.0.2
    - thinc==7.4.0
    - tqdm==4.45.0
    - urllib3==1.25.8
    - wasabi==0.6.0
    - zipp==3.1.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a conda `environment.yml` file. It can be used to create a conda environment, like so

```
conda env create --file requirements.txt
```

Also see [How to make new anaconda env from yml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48016351)