# No module named 'cartopy' + Concepts

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, conda, cartopy

I am working through the tutorial on this webpage here in a Jupyter notebook on a Mac: https://towardsdatascience.com/kriging-the-french-temperatures-f0389ca908dd.  Near the end of the exercise, I need to install the cartopy package.  However, I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cartopy'
```

I've tried to directly install it by writing:

```
!pip install cartopy
```

but the same error appears.  Reading through a few pages on Stackoverflow and Github suggest there is a conflict with the virtual environments and that this can not be installed with pip, but it has to be conda.

I'm fairly comfortable with Python, but the concept of virtual environments and pip vs. conda is completely foreign to me.  Could someone help me solve this problem, but also explain why I'm unable to just pip install this package?

Thank you!

Comment: "*that doesn't seem to work*" - how so? please expand. Are you using Conda already?

Comment: What I meant was that I get the same error message and I don't know if I'm using conda.

Comment: Try running command without an `!` in front of the pip so like this `pip install cartopy`

Comment: To follow on what @Flow suggests, for future reference, don't use an exclamation point with `pip` anymore. **Anything showing that is outdated.** Now for both `pip` & `conda` there are magics, `%pip` and `%conda`. When used in the notebook, they help insure installing to the environment backing the notebook. Since automagics is usually enabled by default, without any symbol means the magic version gets used behind-the-scenes. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more information about those magic commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use and understand virtual environments. pip and conda are both tools for this. Generally conda is preferred for cartopy as is will install non-Python tools like GDAL ([cartopy installation docs](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/installing.html)). Essentially, an environment manager like conda helps you keep multiple environments on your computer with differing versions of packages.

Read about environment management with conda [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)

For your specific case, you need to:

1. Download and install conda
2. Make an environment file listing the packages you need. This will be a plaintext file called environment.yml

```yaml
name: mapmaker # or whatever you want to to call it 
channels:
  - conda-forge # this is the repo that contains cartopy, among other tools
dependencies:
        - ipython # for jupyter notebooks
        - numpy
        - pandas
        - cartopy # you can keep adding more packages here
```

3. Create an environment using this file (only need to do this once)

`conda env create -f environment.yml` ([See this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59686678/13208790))

4. Activate the environment (you do this every time you need it)

`conda activate mapmaker`

conda is a versatile tool. I recommend reading their docs and searching for some tutorials on using conda for environment management

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer!  I followed all the steps you listed and got the same error:  No module named cartopy.  I tried inserting the line:
!conda install -c conda-forge cartopy before the import cartopy line in the cell but got the same error again.