# I have the following error when I install !pip install pandas-profiling

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

**I have the following error when I install !pip install pandas-profiling**

***!pip install pandas-profiling***

Collecting pandas-profiling
Downloading pandas_profiling-3.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (262 kB)

Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.24.0 in c:**\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas-profiling) (2.27.1)

Requirement already satisfied: tqdm>=4.48.2 in c:**\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas-profiling) (4.64.0)

Collecting tangled-up-in-unicode==0.2.0

Downloading tangled_up_in_unicode-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (4.7 MB)

Collecting pydantic>=1.8.1

Downloading pydantic-1.9.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (2.0 MB)

Requirement already satisfied: seaborn>=0.10.1 in c:**\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pandas-profiling) (0.11.2)

Collecting multimethod>=1.4

**ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Acesso negado: 'C:\***\***\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\~arkupsafe\_speedups.cp39-win_amd64.pyd'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.**

What does that mean?

Comment: please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a question

Comment: Please use current best practices to use pip inside a notebook cell. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) about the modern magics. You'd want to use `%pip install` and not `!pip install`. (More can be found in my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72280260/8508004)). You don't say where you found the suggestion to use `!pip`, however, know that it is outdated advice. There's no guarantee use of the magic `%pip` this will fix this issue. But knowing about this will serve you better going forward.