# How to create an environment from a .yml file

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have a .yml file that I would like to create a python environment with called icesattest.yml It is in my downloads folder. When I run the following command in the Anaconda Prompt:

```
conda env create -f icesattest.yml
```

I get the following error:

```
EnvironmentFileNotFound: 'C:\Users\scox4\icesattest.yml' file not found
```

How do I tell the Anaconda prompt to look for the .yml at C:\Users\scox4\downloads\icesattest.yml? Or, how do I move the .yml file to this path so it is read? I tried to drag and drop icesattest.yml to the My PC sidebar on file explorer but it wouldn't let me move it there. I know this is a really silly mistake but I am a complete novice so any simply advice would help!

I searched and found the command that is used to create environments from .yml files so I copy pasted it as so but it failed. I changed the command to match the icesattest.yml file and it still did not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make new anaconda env from yml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48016351/how-to-make-new-anaconda-env-from-yml-file)

Comment: Give the full path of the file to the `-f` argument.

Answer (score 0):

The way I typically handle this is via the `env update` command. I've found it to be a bit more robust when it comes to working with environment files.

```bash
conda env update -n <name of virtual environment> -f environment.yml
```

This command works both with existing environments and with new environments.

I should mention that I typically work with Linux and not Windows, so I can only guarantee that this will work well with unix systems. I'd recommend you check out something like [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install) if you can, as working with Linux is typically a lot easier than Windows once you get the hang of it.

If you want to read more about conda environments: https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#updating-an-environment